# duplicity Exclude Globbing ** Asterisk not working as expected

Tags: duplicity

I try to backup all Maildir of all users with duplicity. But for some reason it excludes the largest one. Some background information:

- /Users/userA/Maildir has >5GB in Maildir
- /Users/userB/Maildir has <10MB in Maildir
- /Users/userC/Maildir has <10MB in Maildir
- /Users/userD/Maildir has <10MB in Maildir

If I run this command (same problem without `--dry-run`, it just shows the issue faster):

> duplicity --dry-run --encrypt-key AAAABBBB --include
>   '/Users/*/Maildir' --exclude '**' /Users
>   sftp://USER@SERVER//private-backup/BACKUPFOLDER/

it would exclude all files of the largest user in /Users/userA/Maildir as you can see it considers only 24.8 MB. All other users are included in the backup if I `list-current-files` afterwards running not as `--dry-run`

```
--------------[ Sicherungsstatistiken ]--------------
StartTime 1576227515.48 (Fri Dec 13 09:58:35 2019)
EndTime 1576227515.63 (Fri Dec 13 09:58:35 2019)
ElapsedTime 0.15 (0.15 seconds)
SourceFiles 670
SourceFileSize 26000373 (24.8 MB)
NewFiles 382
NewFileSize 26000373 (24.8 MB)
DeletedFiles 0
ChangedFiles 0
ChangedFileSize 0 (0 bytes)
ChangedDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes)
DeltaEntries 382
RawDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes)
TotalDestinationSizeChange 0 (0 bytes)
Errors 0
-----------------------------------------------------
```

however if I change the source from `/Users` to `/Users/userA/Maildir` it would backup all mails of UserA but (of course) not for the others:

> duplicity --dry-run --encrypt-key AAAABBBB --include
>   '/Users/*/Maildir' --exclude '**' /Users/userA/Maildir
>   sftp://USER@SERVER//private-backup/BACKUPFOLDER/

```
--------------[ Sicherungsstatistiken ]--------------
StartTime 1576227552.38 (Fri Dec 13 09:59:12 2019)
EndTime 1576227563.13 (Fri Dec 13 09:59:23 2019)
ElapsedTime 10.74 (10.74 seconds)
SourceFiles 69940
SourceFileSize 6268572008 (5.84 GB)
NewFiles 34988
NewFileSize 6268572008 (5.84 GB)
DeletedFiles 0
ChangedFiles 0
ChangedFileSize 0 (0 bytes)
ChangedDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes)
DeltaEntries 34988
RawDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes)
TotalDestinationSizeChange 0 (0 bytes)
Errors 0
-----------------------------------------------------
```

So what could be wrong here? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I searched the internet for hours, and finally found the embarrassing solution by coincidence on my own:

The Maildir (for what reason ever) has a capital D MailDir in the folder for the UserA.